# Can a Layered Window span two displays?

Tags: windows, winapi

Not getting into why such a thing would want to be done in the first place... just wondering if such a thing is possible. Just to be clear, this would be a transparent window with the WS_EX_LAYERED flag, stretched across more than 1 monitor.

thanks,
AH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can - otherwise it would be broken to drag-move a layered window between two monitors. While it's on both monitors, the window looks normal on both displays.

Comment: My problem is understanding the device context side of it. I guess that the destination device context provided to the UpdateLayeredWindow call needs to be null so that the default color palettes for each screen can be used?

Comment: @anderl: The handle you get if you call GetDC(NULL) is valid for the entire desktop, not just one monitor. If the different monitors have different capabilities then that DC will take care of things (perhaps with a speed and/or quality hit, but that is rarely worht worrying about these days). With different monitors you might get better and/or faster results using a DC specific to each monitor (where possible, which isn't the case if a window straddles two monitors) but you can always use the desktop-wide DC for any or all monitor(s).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then - I wasn't sure if something like was handled behind the scenes. Thanks for the clarification.